# PDF.js Progressive loading not working while loading pdf from sub domain

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

When i load pdf within same domain progressive loading is working fine.

But when i load pdf from another domain i am getting Refused to get unsafe header "Accept-Ranges" error. And PDF loads fine but progressive (bit range) thing is not working.

[image]
Anyway to fix that?

Comment: So allowing "Accept-Ranges" header on subdomain via CORS did not work? What browsers and web servers are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF that you are requesting need to be returned by server with an additional CORS header.

See FAQ for more details: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-xhr